# Time Series Modeling with prediction

Tags: python, time-series

I have a dataset with time columns and other numerical columns: here is the sample file:
[image]

I want to use the data for 6 months and predict the values for numerical columns for the next 3 months based on historical data, Which model can help me predict?
All the numerical columns are supposed to be considered for prediction.

Comment: It depends - you could treat this as a univariate or multivariate problem. In a univariate problem, you consider each column separately. In a multivariate problem, you forecast a column using other columns as covariates. Multivariate methods are more complicated, but can help if the other columns are correlated with the time series of interest. Your question does not specify whether one column is useful in predicting other columns.

Comment: PS: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: No the columns are not correlated and Need to consider a multivariate problem

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this a python specific question, but more of a statistical/forecasting question.

One standard method you can use is Auto regressive models like ARIMA, using the statsmodel python package.(https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.html).